# Quicker way to filter out data based on a particular value

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with a workbook that currently has 3 sheets. The first sheet is an overview where the filtered data will appear. Cell `D11` has the color that I am looking for. Upon entering the color cells `F3:I27` Populate with information like color, shape, number and animal.

[C2C-Tracker2](http://1drv.ms/1HE5PLr)

I would use a Pivot Table for this, however, I have another set of data in `K3:M27`. This data is pulled from another sheet within the workbook with a similar function.

The formula that I am using is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(cases!A:A,SMALL(IF(EXACT($D$3,cases!$C:$C),ROW(cases!$C:$C)-ROW($F$1)+1),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Of course it is entered using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> for it to work properly.

I tried using a VBA Macro that I pulled from the video below:

[Excel VBA Loop to Find Records Matching Search Criteria](https://youtu.be/QOxhRSCfHaw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many array formulas can really make your workbook very slow.

Here is a code to populate `Dataset1` using arrays. **It runs in less than a second**.

Hope this gets you started. I have commented the code but if you still have a problem understanding, just post back :)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim DSOne() As String
    Dim tmpAr As Variant

    Dim wsCas As Worksheet: Set wsCas = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cases")
    Dim wsMain As Worksheet: Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long

    '~~> Check if user entered a color
    If wsMain.Range("D3").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a color first", vbCritical, "Missing Color"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '~~> Clear data for input in main sheet
    wsMain.Range("F3:F" & wsMain.Rows.Count).ClearContents

    '~~> Get last row of Sheet Cases
    lRow = wsCas.Range("A" & wsCas.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With wsCas
        '~~> Get count of cells which have that color
        i = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Columns(3), wsMain.Range("D3").Value)

        '~~> Check if there is any color
        If i > 0 Then
            '~~> Define your array to hold those values
            ReDim DSOne(1 To i, 1 To 4)
            '~~> Store the Sheet Cases data in the array
            tmpAr = .Range("A1:D" & lRow).Value

            j = 1

            '~~> Loop through the array to find the matches
            For i = LBound(tmpAr) To UBound(tmpAr)
                If tmpAr(i, 3) = wsMain.Range("D3").Value Then
                    DSOne(j, 1) = tmpAr(i, 1)
                    DSOne(j, 2) = tmpAr(i, 2)
                    DSOne(j, 3) = tmpAr(i, 3)
                    DSOne(j, 4) = tmpAr(i, 4)
                    j = j + 1
                End If
            Next i

            '~~> write to the main sheet in 1 Go!
            wsMain.Range("F3").Resize(UBound(DSOne), 4).Value = DSOne
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**:

[image]
Using the above approach now populate `Dataset2` :)

Comment: Love the code, works just like I was wanting for Data Set 1. One thing that I am wondering is how to apply it to Data Set 2 as the data there does not hold the same values as the first set.  Not sure if you looked at the 'calls' sheet or not but there's not much of anything specific to grab on to like the color portion. Something tells me I am just missing a specific line to get the data to work. I am just wondering how I can pull the first "ACD" after "RING" value and show the date, time and length in that data set. (also I really appreciate the help as I am trying to really learn). :D

Comment: Yes I did see the 2nd sheet as well :). Once you store the data in the array, loop through the array to test your `IF` condition with "ACD" after "RING" and then copy them to the 2nd array :)